# CSS text respect border radius

Tags: html, css

## Hello there!

I need a nice cool effect of border radius. So i made a div with this CSS:

```
div#second
{
    max-width: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 200px;
    padding-right: 110px;
    padding-left: 110px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

div#second p 
{
    text-align: none;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Inside it, there is a Paragraph tag with some text. The thing is, the text inside of it either overflows the div, or leaves too much blank space. Here you can see what I mean:
[image]

[image]

What i'd like is to make the text use all the space inside de div without overflowing it. I have tried to "overflow-wrap: break-word;", but the result is the same as the second image here. 
I can't make an image with text already inside because I want it to be responsive.

Wwhat's the secret CSS behind this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using hidden `div` elements with the [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) css rule. You could control the flow of the text very precisely by using `shape-outside` to define polygons that would 'push' the text into the shape you need.

Comment: Could you give an example here please? Eventually with pictures too. Or it feels a bit "link only" and not usable as-is.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple workaround for this would be to add a transparent image to the corners where the text overlaps and have the text wrap around the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using padding

```
 div#second p 
    {
        text-align: none;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        color:#fff;
        padding:20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the short answer is that there is no simple way for you to do this. With `border-radius`, or even `clip-path`, the browser renders these elements as boxes.

Now that we got that out of the way, there are a few ways that you might approach this problem:

1. An option would be to use mixins to help shape your text inside of a non-box container https://skeate.github.io/2015/07/13/Wrapping-Text-to-Fit-Shaped-Containers-with-CSS.html

This option might take some overhead but it seems like the closest thing to what you need

2. If you know the end-result dimensions of your div and your text will always be the same, you can potentially create multiple divs inside of your parent div and add padding accordingly. (This is just some food for thought, since I know you want the div to be responsive)

Let me know if you have any more questions :)